# How to configure the logger in netty using customized log4j.xml?

Tags: log4j, netty

Netty and Hibernate are used in my project. And I have  log4j.xml and commons-logging.properties in the source folder.
The code in commons-logging.properties is

```
org.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger
```

Hibernate could log successfully using the configuration in log4j.xml, but netty couldn't.

There is no such user manual to teach me how to configure the logger in netty. so please help me.

Comment: [Updating the answer for Log4j2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40255418/netty-internal-logger-issue/42894636#42894636)

Answer (score 5):

You can set the logger in Netty via

```
InternalLoggerFactory.setDefaultFactory(new Log4JLoggerFactory());
```

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Thank you! That is really what I am looking for! I can set the logger factory to commonslogger, so that commons-logging will be totally used in my project.