# Netty internal logger issue

Tags: java, netty, log4j2

I am using Netty 4.1.6.
Is it possible to set netty using log4j2 as internal logger?
Eclipse prompt me that the following statement is depreciated.

```
InternalLoggerFactory.setDefaultFactory(new Log4J2LoggerFactory());
```

Would you tell me how to do so?

Comment: The source code for [Log4J2LoggerFactory](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/eb7f751ba519cbcab47d640cd18757f09d077b55/common/src/main/java/io/netty/util/internal/logging/Log4J2LoggerFactory.java) states "@deprecated Use {@link #INSTANCE} instead.". So you probably should use `InternalLoggerFactory.setDefaultFactory( Log4J2LoggerFactory.INSTANCE);`

This was added according to the discussions in [PR 5047](https://github.com/netty/netty/pull/5047), and following the discussion it seems they wanted to make all log implemntations singleton classes

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ferrybig for the tip.

I am elaborating on how to do this on log4j2.

Before you do the Netty server bootstrap, insert this line above.

```
InternalLoggerFactory.setDefaultFactory(Log4J2LoggerFactory.INSTANCE);
ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
b.option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 1024);
b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
 .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
 .handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO))
 .childHandler(new ...
```

Then on the log4j2.xml have the loggers and the corresponding Appenders.

```
<Logger name="io.netty" level="INFO" additivity="false">
   <AppenderRef ref="nettyTrace"/>
</Logger>
```